# get_header('header2') not working properly in child themes

Tags: themes, child-theme

I am trying to replace header-header2.php of my main theme in my child theme and by adding the file in the child theme, but wordpress is loading the file from the main theme itself. Is the second header not supported in a child theme???

In index.php, I am using get_header('header2') to call the file.

Anyone knows how to do this. Please help, its urgent!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an index.php in your child theme why not use `get_header('child')` and use `header-child.php` to display the header.

Comment: Nice idea, so simple and efficient....